Why including padding to the nearest scrollport changes the threshold position of the sticky element where it sticks?
As per my understanding, for Sticky Positioning Scheme, the CSS spec defines that the insets applied to an sticky element is relative to the edges of the nearest scrollport which then forms the Sticky View Rectangle (SVR). And so, the edges of the SVR determines the threshold at which the sticky element actually sticks.

Sticky positioning is similar to relative positioning except the offsets are automatically calculated in reference to the nearest scrollport.
For a sticky positioned box, the inset properties represent insets from the respective edges of the nearest scrollport, defining the sticky view rectangle used to constrain the box’s position.

Also, the CSS spec defines scrollport and nearest scrollport as follows:

The visual “viewport” of a scroll container (through which the scrollable overflow area can be viewed) coincides with its padding box, and is called the scrollport. A box’s nearest scrollport is the scrollport of its nearest scroll container ancestor.

 The fillers in the code are just there so that the sticky and scrolling behaviour of the .sticky element can be clearly seen.
Consider the following code snippet:


.scrollport {
  width: 70%;
  height: 250px;

  overflow: auto;
}

.filler {
  height: 110%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.container-filler {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;

  border: 3px solid slateblue;
}
<div class="scrollport">
  <div class="filler"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-filler"></div>
    <div class="sticky">Sticky Element</div>
    <div class="container-filler"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="filler"></div>
</div>



For the above code, as the top and bottom insets are set to 0px, the edges of the SVR coincides with the scrollport. Hence, when the threshold is met, the .sticky element sticks until either it reaches its normal position (for bottom: 0px) or it reaches the boundary of its container (for top: 0px) after which, it scrolls with its container.
Now, consider the following snippet with padding added to the .scrollport element.


.scrollport {
  width: 70%;
  height: 250px;

  padding: 20px 0; /* added top and bottom padding */

  overflow: auto;
}

.filler {
  height: 110%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.container-filler {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;

  border: 3px solid slateblue;
}
<div class="scrollport">
  <div class="filler"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-filler"></div>
    <div class="sticky">Sticky Element</div>
    <div class="container-filler"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="filler"></div>
</div>



As one can notice that when top and bottom padding are added to the .scrollport, the .sticky element doesn't stick at the given threshold.
The edges of the SVR do not coincide with the edges of the scrollport. The top padding pushes down the top edge of the SVR whereas the bottom padding pushes the bottom edge of the SVR up.
As quoted already above, to form the SVR, the insets are applied relative to the respective edges of the nearest scrollport and the scrollport coincides with the padding box of the scroll container.
This means that the added padding to the scrollport should not affect the position of the SVR. In either cases, as top: 0px and bottom: 0px, the SVR position should coincide with the scrollport (or in other words, its padding box).
Instead, the insets are applied after taking padding into account. Hence, the insets effectively positions the SVR relative to the content box of the scrollport and not to the padding box of the scrollport.

Question
So, isn't this behaviour in the Sticky Positioning Scheme of forming the SVR contradicts what actually is stated in the CSS spec?
Or is it just that I am interpreting the spec wrongly and this behaviour is expected? If this is the case, can anyone please explain where I am going wrong?
Also, is it documented anywhere in the spec?

I think the definition of scrollport and nearest scrollport alone doesn't explain the sticky behavior. The padding-box part explains what is inside the scroll (not related to the sticky behavior)
Check this example:


.box {
  margin: 50px;
  border: 50px solid red;
  padding: 50px;
  background: green;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box div {
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>



I have added margin, border, padding and we have the content. Only the padding and content are "inside the scroll" and this is the padding-box referred to in the specification.
But when defining the offset of the sticky position we consider the nearest scrollport element but the padding-box thing is no considered. In the Spec you can read somewhere: "insofar as it can while its position box remains contained within its containing block." and the containing block of an element is always the content-box of the parent (or an ancestor) expect for absolute element where it's the padding-box.
I know it's a bit confusing but basically you have two things. The padding-box explain how the scroll mechanism work and what is considered inside the scroll. Then you have the sticky behavior that is restricted by the containing block rule.

I think your answer is half right in the sense that the scrollport of a scroll container includes its padding box and not its border or margin box. But the point is still not resolved that why the insets are applied to form the SVR after taking padding into account because SVR is part of the scrollport and so of its padding box.
More than the why, I am eager to know if this behaviour is expected and does it go as per the standard.
It'd be great if you can provide more light on this.

I too thought of the containing block rule but for .sticky, its containing block is the content box of the .container and not of the .scrollport element as stated in the MDN docs and CSS spec as well. And this is very well followed by the .sticky element in both the code snippets.

Upon reading your answer again, I noticed that I misunderstood this part a little bit: "the containing block of an element is always the content-box of the parent (or an ancestor)" where I thought you meant that the containing block for the .sticky element is the content box of .scrollport. And that's why I thought of clarifying this in the previous comment. But the actual point is still unresolved highlighted in the 1st comment.
